# Trouble with Type Error "array.slice is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, native, slice, array.prototype.map

I am trying to slice an array thats holding Json data taken by yelps API and its giving me a type error message, saying that it is not a function. I believe its saying that the array is not a valid data type to use the method .slice() What is another method for passing Json data into a component as a prop?

```
state = { businesses: [], profileIndex: 0 };

componentWillMount() {
axios.get('https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search', config)
.then(response => this.setState({ businesses: response.data }));
}

upcomingCard = () => {
this.setState({profileIndex: this.state.profileIndex + 1});
}

displayPlace = () => {
const {profileIndex, businesses} = this.state;    
{businesses.slice(profileIndex, profileIndex + 1).map(place => {
  return (
    <SwipeCard
    key={place.id}
    place={place}
    onSwipeOff={this.upcomingCard}
    />
  );
 })
}}

render() {
console.log(this.state.businesses);

return (
  <View style={{flex:1}}>
    {this.displayPlace()}
  </View>
);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it, it was extra data that it did not need, So what I did was this

```
componentWillMount() {
 axios.get('https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search', config)
.then(response => this.setState({ businesses: response.data.businesses 
 }));
}
```

I had to go dipper into the Json data if you will.